# Set is Unbounded

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be a nonempty set and $U$ be an open set contained in $S$. Let $C$ be a closed set such that $S\subseteq C$. Assume that $C\setminus U=\emptyset$. Prove that $S$ is unbounded.

I have that U=S=C, and thus S must be both open and closed. The only two cases that fit this criteria are the null set and the real line. However, we are assuming that S is nonempty, and thus S must be the real line. The real line is by definition unbounded.  Is this proof correct or does it need to be modified?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? (Also, where is this problem taking place? It's not true in general . . .)

Comment: I don't know where to start with this problem. I know that by definition S is unbounded means that there does not exist any x such that s<=x for each s in S or any y such that s>=y for any s in S. And that's all the problem says; I don't know where it is taking place.

Comment: Is $S$ a subset of real numbers?

Comment: You need to specify the space you are in. For example, in the space $X=(0,1)$ the set $C=S=U=X$ satisfies all conditions but is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $U \subseteq S \subseteq C$, but since $C \setminus U = \emptyset$ we must have $U=S=C$